# Dialog only opens once

Tags: jquery

How do I set the 'autoOpen' and 'open' for this Dialog. Please help!

```
<body>
<img class="image" src="css/images/0101-s.png">
<img src="css/images/0101.png" style="display: none;"class="dialog">

<img class="image" src="css/images/0102-s.png">
<img src="css/images/0102.png" style="display: none;"class="dialog">

<script>
$('.image').click  (function(){
        $(this).next('.dialog').dialog({ show: 'slide', minWidth: 400 });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't waste resources creating a dialog on every click. Do it like this:

```
$('.dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'slide',
    minWidth: 400
});
$('.image').click(function() {
    $('.dialog').eq($(this).index('.image')).dialog('open');
})​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p5PGa/)**.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, the dialog opens only the first image no matter which image you click.

Comment: Hmmm, no it doesn't. try this jsFiddle with a different image and you'll see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p5PGa/2/

Comment: You're right. I guess there's something wrong with my HTML code cuz I keep on getting only the first image.

Comment: Hmmm, why not post the code you're having problems with if it's not reflected in the original question? Oh, and feel free to make this the accepted answer again ;)

Comment: @j08691 $('.dialog').eq($(this).index()) - Is this a reliable solution to determine the closest dialog to that image. I understand it is works fine.. but still.. I am simply not confident to rely on .index() to determine the related dialog. May be it is just me.

Comment: This is my HTML`<div class="left">
 <div class="box">
  <img class="image" src="css/images/0101-s.png">
  <img src="css/images/0101.png" style="display: none;"class="dialog">
 </div></div>
 <div class="right">
 <div class="box">
  <img class="image" src="css/images/0102-s.png">
  <img style="display: none;"src="css/images/0102.png"class="dialog">
 </div></div>
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
 <div class="right">
 <div class="box">
  <img class="image" src="css/images/0103-s.png">
  <img style="display: none;"src="css/images/0103.png"class="dialog"></div>
      </div>`

Comment: No problem, updated the code in my answer and here's an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p5PGa/3/

Comment: I really appreciated your help. Thanks again. One more thing, if you can explain a little what went wrong, so I can understand what's going on not just copy and paste.

Comment: No, the difference between your first jquey code and the second where you passed .dialog into index.

Comment: Oh, I just explicitly gave .index() the selector to look for. Nothing major.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to initialize the dialog every time the image is clicked. You should call `$('.dialog').dialog("open")` after the initialization to open the dialog.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/p5PGa/1/)

Try below code,

```
//initialize the dialogs
$('.image').each(function(index) {
    var dialogID = 'dlg-' + index;
    $(this).next('.dialog').dialog({
        show: 'slide',
        minWidth: 400,
        create: function(event, ui) { 
            $(this).addClass(dialogID);
        },
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $(this).data('dlgID', dialogID);
});

$('.image').click(function() {
    var dialogID = $(this).data('dlgID');
    $('.' + dialogID ).dialog("open");
});
```

You code doesn't work because the dialog is no more in `.next()` of the `.image`. The jQuery dialog widget appends the dialog to the body tag and so `$(this).next('.dialog')` in your code is empty. See below snapshots,

Before Dialog Initialization,

[image]

After Dialog Initialization,

[image]

Comment: Still not working, after the initial open nothing happens when clicking on the image. Any other suggestions? please

Comment: @user1157575 Did you try the 2nd approach. It should work. When you say not working, do you mean that it is not opening 2nd time?

Comment: @user1157575 I think the problem is with the $(this).next('.dialog') is empty coz the dialog wraps a lot of widget and append it to the body..

Comment: @user1157575 See my updated code and the demo for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
$('.image').click  (function(){
    $(this).next('.dialog').dialog({ show: 'slide', minWidth: 400, autoOpen: true });
});
```

in this way when you click the image you open the dialog. If you want you can define an open function that does something when the dialog opens.

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.dialog').dialog({
        show: 'slide',
        minWidth: 400,
        autoOpen: true,
        open: function(){
            alert('hi');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still opens only once

Comment: @user1157575 what do you mean with only once?You want more dialogs?One for each click?

Comment: I can only click on the image once, after that it doesn't open.